# How to justify anchor tag in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to justify links but its not working when have few links in a div.

```css
div#locs_list>div {
  text-align: justify;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-box" id="locs_list">
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Westchester County</a></h4>
  <div><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Ardsley">ardsley</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Armonk">armonk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Bedford">bedford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Briarcliff Manor">briarcliff manor</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Bronxville">bronxville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Chappaqua">chappaqua</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Dobbs Ferry">dobbs ferry</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Eastchester">eastchester</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Elmsford">elmsford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Harrison">harrison</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hartsdale">hartsdale</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hastings-on-hudson">hastings-on-hudson</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Hawthorne">hawthorne</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Irvington">irvington</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Larchmont">larchmont</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mamaroneck">mamaroneck</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Mount Kisco">mount kisco</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mount Vernon">mount vernon</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="New Rochelle">new rochelle</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Pelham">pelham</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Pleasantville">pleasantville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Port Chester">port chester</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Purchase">purchase</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Rye">rye</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Scarsdale">scarsdale</a>
    <a
      class="loc_aList" href="" title="Sleepy Hollow">sleepy hollow</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tarrytown">tarrytown</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Thornwood">thornwood</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tuckahoe">tuckahoe</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Valhalla">valhalla</a>
      <a
        class="loc_aList" href="" title="White Plains">white plains</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Yonkers">yonkers</a></div>
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Fairfield County</a></h4>
  <div><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Darien">darien</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Greenwich">greenwich</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Norwalk">norwalk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Stamford">stamford</a></div>
</div>
```

Output

[image]

You can see that "Westchester County" links are justified but Fairfield County are not.

IF less content then it should look like this

[image]

Comment: I would expect the output to look exactly like the first image. Why would it suddenly become narrower than the div? Where do you define "less content should not be spaced out" ?

Comment: You do realize that what your example shows has _nothing_ to do with `text-align: justify`, and everything with flexbox - no?

Comment: … which makes your question, as it is right now, pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936543/left-align-last-row-of-flexbox-using-space-between-and-margins, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` doesn't work for the anchors. The way I see it is to use flexbox and set the last anchor to have `margin-right: auto`. Also, set each anchor to have default margin.

```css
div#locs_list>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#locs_list a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#locs_list a:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-box" id="locs_list">
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Westchester County</a></h4>
  <div><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Ardsley">ardsley</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Armonk">armonk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Bedford">bedford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Briarcliff Manor">briarcliff manor</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Bronxville">bronxville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Chappaqua">chappaqua</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Dobbs Ferry">dobbs ferry</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Eastchester">eastchester</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Elmsford">elmsford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Harrison">harrison</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hartsdale">hartsdale</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hastings-on-hudson">hastings-on-hudson</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Hawthorne">hawthorne</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Irvington">irvington</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Larchmont">larchmont</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mamaroneck">mamaroneck</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Mount Kisco">mount kisco</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mount Vernon">mount vernon</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="New Rochelle">new rochelle</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Pelham">pelham</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Pleasantville">pleasantville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Port Chester">port chester</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Purchase">purchase</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Rye">rye</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Scarsdale">scarsdale</a>
    <a
      class="loc_aList" href="" title="Sleepy Hollow">sleepy hollow</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tarrytown">tarrytown</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Thornwood">thornwood</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tuckahoe">tuckahoe</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Valhalla">valhalla</a>
      <a
        class="loc_aList" href="" title="White Plains">white plains</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Yonkers">yonkers</a></div>
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Fairfield County</a></h4>
  <div><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Darien">darien</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Greenwich">greenwich</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Norwalk">norwalk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Stamford">stamford</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use justify with the 'a' tag not with div.

```css
#locs_list p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags-box" id="locs_list">
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Westchester County</a></h4>
  <div>
<p><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Ardsley">ardsley</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Armonk">armonk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Bedford">bedford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Briarcliff Manor">briarcliff manor</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Bronxville">bronxville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Chappaqua">chappaqua</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Dobbs Ferry">dobbs ferry</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Eastchester">eastchester</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Elmsford">elmsford</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Harrison">harrison</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hartsdale">hartsdale</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Hastings-on-hudson">hastings-on-hudson</a><a class="loc_aList"
      href="" title="Hawthorne">hawthorne</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Irvington">irvington</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Larchmont">larchmont</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mamaroneck">mamaroneck</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Mount Kisco">mount kisco</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Mount Vernon">mount vernon</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="New Rochelle">new rochelle</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Pelham">pelham</a><a class="loc_aList" href=""
      title="Pleasantville">pleasantville</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Port Chester">port chester</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Purchase">purchase</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Rye">rye</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Scarsdale">scarsdale</a>
    <a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Sleepy Hollow">sleepy hollow</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tarrytown">tarrytown</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Thornwood">thornwood</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Tuckahoe">tuckahoe</a>
    <a
      class="loc_aList" href="" title="Valhalla">valhalla</a>
      <a class="loc_aList" href="" title="White Plains">white plains</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Yonkers">yonkers</a></div>
  <h4 class="lab_title"><a href="" title="" class="no_atag_title">Fairfield County</a></h4>
  <div><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Darien">darien</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Greenwich">greenwich</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Norwalk">norwalk</a><a class="loc_aList" href="" title="Stamford">stamford</a>
</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does nothing. Please test before answering. See the snippet you could have made